# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/kernel with Tensorflow/Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a CNN model with help of the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Create_CNN:
  def _conv(self, input, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride):
    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input,
                            filters=nChannels,
                            kernel_size=kernelSize,
                            strides=(kernelStride, kernelStride),
                            padding='same',
                            activation=tf.nn.relu
                            )
    return conv

  def create_cnn(self, input, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride):
    input = tf.reshape(input, shape=[-1, 500, 530, 3])
    layer1 = Create_CNN()._conv(input, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride)
    layer2 = Create_CNN()._conv(layer1, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride)
    layer3 = Create_CNN()._conv(layer2, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride)
    layer4 = Create_CNN()._conv(layer3, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride)
    layer5 = Create_CNN()._conv(layer4, nChannels, kernelSize, kernelStride)
    return layer5
```

Here, my input is a 500 * 530 * 3 dimension image. I am trying pass input and other parameters using following code:

```
with tf.Session().as_default():
      tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
      i = PlantUtils().create_instance('ara2013_plant001_rgb.png', 'ara2013_plant001_label.png', 500, 530, 100, 106, 1, 1,
                                 1)
      input_image = i[0] # It is a 500 * 530 * 3 tensor
      b = Create_CNN().create_cnn(input=input_image, kernelSize=3, kernelStride=1, nChannels=30)
      x = tf.argmax(input=b, axis=1)
      print x.eval()
```

When I am trying to print logits(means value of x) I am getting the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/kernel
```

I am not sure what wrong I did. I need to see the logits generated from my CNN model. I really need help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are running the initializer **before** building the graph. Ideally you should build the `Graph` before creating a `Session`. Try this

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  i = PlantUtils().create_instance('ara2013_plant001_rgb.png', 'ara2013_plant001_label.png', 500, 530, 100, 106, 1, 1, 1)
  input_image = i[0] # It is a 500 * 530 * 3 tensor
  b = Create_CNN().create_cnn(input=input_image, kernelSize=3, kernelStride=1, nChannels=30)
  x = tf.argmax(input=b, axis=1)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(x)
```

Comment: @Saurabh Saxena. I have got a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778555/failedpreconditionerror-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-value-conv2d-1-89-kerne . I would be very pleased about any help I can get. As you solved this problem, i thought you might be able to find the mistake in our code. Sorry for writing you here. We are just very despaired right now